# Is it correct to say "I wished I had learnt something somehow"

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

Is it correct to say `"I wished I had learnt something somehow"`|| Is there a better way to say it in few words ?? (After much practicing I felt I was not getting good at a skill, so, in my childhood days I wished I could become skillful, sure, I did not want to skip the process but was sometimes frustrated so to speak)

Timeline: **childhood** days, wishing for the **future**; which was not a reality in **the then present time**.

I want to express a feeling that I had in the past. And in that point in time, I had a strong desire to learn a skill but was in the process of learning.

**Context**
We all know learning a skill takes time and perseverance. But we sometimes become impatient as the process of becoming a pro from novice is time consuming. Hence, we start wishing "Somehow I be as good as xyz(pro)" etc.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: If your parents had recorded a video of you when you were a child expressing this thought what would you be saying?  “I wish I could already play the piano.”  “I wish I already knew how to play.”

Comment: Wow, glad that you came up with a good illustration and a nice way to express this thought. You are right, I would construct my sentence that way. However, my question is, how will I explain this whole experience to someone else without using direct speech, For example, in the above case, My parents recorded a video, and in that video, --->I expressed how I wished I could play the piano? <--.....it sounds better than....I wished I had learnt piano somehow (doesn't sound good to my ears).. modal auxiliary "could" made the difference.....Is this the solution to my problem?

Comment: Exactly.  I first wanted to make sure I understood what you wanted to say and I figured it would be easier to do that in present tense.  Then we can put it in the past:  “I wished I already knew how to play.” “ I wished I could already play”

Comment: Could you post this as an answer I would be glad to mark this thread as close! Thanks for everything.

Comment: Also, one last question,  Is this incorrect ?---> I wished I had learnt piano somehow

Comment: It’s ok, not my preference. The ’somehow’ is ambiguous.  I would say, “I wished that somehow I had already learned to play.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments section (credit goes to Jim)!

It’s ok, not my preference. The ’somehow’ is ambiguous. I would say, `“I wished that somehow I had already learned to play.”`